# Error al Mostrar Grafica Estadistica highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Buen dia. Estoy tratando de generar una gráfica empleando JS y Highcharts. Como fuente de datos utilizo un procedimiento almacenado de sql el cual lo añado por entity framework mediante el modelo de datos.

Tengo el siguiente codigo JS,json y html para generar la grafica.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DatosSecond.aspx.cs" Inherits="AppEstudiantes.Aspx.Grafics.DatosSecond" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title></title>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/exporting.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnGrafico").click("click", function () {
                ListaPubli();
            });
        });

        function ListaPubli() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "DatosSecond.aspx/ListaPublicidad",
                data: "{}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (Result) {
                    Result = Result.d;
                    var data = [];
                    for (var i in Result) {
                        var serie = new Array(Result[i].NombreCurso, Result[i].Cantidad);
                        data.push(serie);
                    }
                    DibujaGrafico(data);
                },
                error: function (Result) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
        }

        function DibujaGrafico(series) {
            $('#grafico').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: 1,
                    plotShadow: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Datos Estadisticos'
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Segmentacion Alumnas COLEGIO LA PRESENTACION'
                },
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y} (<b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>)'
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        allowPointSelect: true,
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.y}',
                            style: {
                                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    type: 'pie',
                    name: 'Publicidad',
                    data: series
                }]
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div runat="server" id="divDatos">

    </div>
        <hr/>
        <button type="button" id="btnGrafico">Ver Gráfico</button>
        <input type="button" onclick="location.href = '/Aspx/Students/EstadistsGrafics';" value="Regresar" />
        <hr />
        <div id="grafico"></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

La pagina tiene una extensión .aspx, por lo tanto tiene un codebehind en el cual añado un WebMethod y retornar el conjunto de propiedad del procedimento almacenado.

```
[WebMethod()]
        public static List<CantidadAlumasporgrupos_Result> ListaPublicidad()
        {
            AppestadisticaEntities db = new AppestadisticaEntities();
            return db.CantidadAlumasporgrupos().ToList();
        }
```

esta es mi consulta sql

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CantidadAlumasporgrupos]
as 

        select NombreCurso,
        (
                SELECT count(*) from Estudiantes
                where Id_Grupo = Grupos.Id_Grupo
        ) 
        as 'Cantidad' 
        from Grupos
where (SELECT count(*) from Estudiantes
                where Id_Grupo = Grupos.Id_Grupo )> 0
```

Mi inconveniente es que al intentar ver la gráfica carga algunos controles de highcharts pero no la grafica. Sale vacia, no se que error puedo estar cometiendo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muestra el valor que se obtiene en **series** para alimentar la **data** del chart, y encantado podría ayudarte.

Comment: el error es que no me muestra la gráfica. Al inspeccionar en el browser no arroja ningún error.

Comment: Muestra la variable series que retorna tu petición ajax para poder replicar tu error.